# Good javascript-graph library

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need do create a pretty complicated graph in Javascript. It's a line-graph with dots that are click-able. I've looked at the google-api, and it just won't do. Also, it needs to be able to rendre several graphs in one window.

Would be really nice if it was powered by jQuery, since the rest of the project is running on that platform.

Does anyone know about any good libraries? I have not gotten across any suitable yet.

Thomas

Comment: There's a fair chance you would have to build it yourself. Also, jQuery isnt a platform, its a library.

Comment: Why is google-api not good for you? If it's it a requirement that no images must be downloaded from third-party server, please write so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)

Comment: Excellent! The Ajax-demo was just what I was looking for. Thank you so much. Can't believe I overlooked this.

Answer (score 1):

Try highcharts:

http://www.highcharts.com/

It uses either jQuery, MooTools or Prototype to run: http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use

There are more jQuery alternatives though: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/

Comment: Excellent! The Ajax-demo was just what I was looking for. Thank you so much. Can't believe I overlooked this.

Answer (score 0):

We are also using HighCharts, but the HighStocks variation.

http://blog.supertext.ch/2011/09/a-new-charting-library-for-the-supertext-website/

We assembled a list of other tools via Choosle. (See factors link)

Answer (score 0):

HighCharts may fit your needs, and it has amazing looks. Have a look at the demo page [line chart with clickable dots](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax) where there is an example of line chart with multiple lines and clickable dots

Answer (score 0):

Flot rocks! It is opensource, so no license costs!

http://code.google.com/p/flot/

You can do amazing things with it. See it's showcase here: http://code.google.com/p/flot/wiki/FlotUsage

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

gRaphaël is a plug-in that extends the super impressive Raphaël JavaScript vector library and provides extensive APIs for canned and 100% custom charts / graphs. It is also MIT licensed, which means it's free for commercial and non-commercial use!

[gRaphaël](http://g.raphaeljs.com/)